# Request for Tag Burnination: [Game-History]

Tags: support, status-completed, burnination

The accused: [game-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history)

This tag has 5 questions, and all of them are closed.

According to [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/how-do-we-feel-towards-specific-questions-about-the-history-of-a-certain-game-me), requests about the history of certain game elements is not something we want. And, if we're asking a question about the history of a specific game, we're just going to tag it with THAT game. We don't need a history tag.

Comment: The questions themselves need to be deleted as well.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I'm not sure about that. Part of me is thinking they aren't detrimental to the site, and they serve as "heads on a stake" - kind of a "don't do this - we close these kinds of questions".

Comment: Now there is [tag:gaming-history].

Comment: And I like the new gaming-history tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've casted the delete votes on the remaining questions, thus deleting the tag.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112779/what-is-the-significance-of-the-lucasarts-golden-guy-logo was a casualty, but it's probably a question better answered by the LucasArts wikipedia page (the answer refers to that page anyway).